# ASP.NET MVC ModelBinders.Binders thread-safety

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I would like to confirm some questions about `ModelBinderDictionary` in asp.net mvc:

A single instance of `ModelBinderDictionary` is stored in `ModelBinders.Binders` static property. So during the whole application lifetime, we will have only one instance of `ModelBinderDictionary`.

But I found that `ModelBinderDictionary` is not thread-safe. What if two threads add model binders to `ModelBinders.Binders` at the same time (not in the Application_Start, but in some controller)?

I guess the reason why `ModelBinderDictionary` is not designed to be thread-safe is that `ModelBinders.Binders` is supposed to be accessed only in application start, so thread-safety is not needed because there'll be only one thread running in Application_Start, correct?

So if we are designing a class supposed to be accessed at any time, we have to make it thread-safe. Otherwise we don't need to guarantee thread-safty and simply do it like ModelBinderDictionary, correct?

So this is also about Trade-Off. Although adding model binders to `ModelBinders.Binders` at any time is allowed, but no one will do that. So we don't need to design for such rare case. That's why we don't guarantee thread-safety for ModelBinderDictionary, correct?